# Python DomainClass list is adding the last entry over and over again

Tags: python

I have a domain dataclass:

```
from pydantic import BaseModel
from pydantic.dataclasses import dataclass

@dataclass(frozen=False)
class ValueObject:
    """
    Base class for value objects
    """

@dataclass(frozen=False)
class Rss(ValueObject):
    index: int
    title: str
    titleDetail: str
```

and then I have a service called "RssFeedReader"

```
"""Services module."""
from typing import Any
from dataclasses import dataclass,field
import feedparser
from pydantic import BaseModel
from DomainModels import Rss

'''force Rss to be a DM & not a module'''
class Rss(BaseModel):
    def __next__(self):
        yield self

@dataclass(kw_only=True)
class RssFeedReader:

    krssResult: list[Rss] = field(default_factory=list)
    
    #public commands    
    async def Read(self, url:str):        
        feed = feedparser.parse(url)["entries"]
        
        kRss = Rss
        for i in range(len(feed)):
            kRss.index = i
            kRss.title = feed[i]["title"]            
            kRss.titleDetail =feed[i]["title_detail"]            
            self.AddResult(i,kRss)            

        return self.krssResult
    

    def AddResult(self, i, rss:Rss):    
        print(i)    
        self.krssResult.append(rss)
```

now for some reason even tho it's iterating over the items and print(i) is stating the index, when I can this all 50 items are a repeat of the last index, its whipped out the first 49 values with a duplicate of the last result,

I have also tried to use insert(i,rss) but that gives me the same issue.

I am calling this in a flask app, and using DI

main.py

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_bootstrap import Bootstrap
from .wiring import init_app

from .Container import Container
from . import views

def create_app() -> Flask:
    container = Container()
    app = Flask("rssfeed")
    app.container = container
    init_app()

    app.add_url_rule("/", "index", views.index)

    bootstrap = Bootstrap()
    bootstrap.init_app(app)

    return app
```

views.py

```
""" app moudle """
from flask import Flask
from dependency_injector.wiring import inject, Provide

from .Container import Container
from .RssFeedService import RssFeedReader

@inject
async def index(rss_feed_service: RssFeedReader = Provide[Container.rss_feed_service]):

    read = await rss_feed_service.Read(url="https://kotaku.com/rss")
    
    return "<h1>News system</h1>" + str(read)
```

container.py

```
from dependency_injector import containers, providers
from . import RssFeedService

class Container(containers.DeclarativeContainer):
    
    wiring_config = containers.WiringConfiguration(modules=[".views"])
    
    rss_feed_service = providers.Factory(
        RssFeedService.RssFeedReader        
    )
```

If I add the title to a black array that travels to the front end fine, its only if I bind to the "krssResult: list[Rss]"  it gives me the issue

Answer (score -1):

I am not entirely sure I understood the question so forgive me in advance if this is not helpful. I am not sure how you are calling your async function but I played with your code using some test RSS Feeds and this way it worked for me more or less as I would have expected it to work:

from dataclasses import dataclass, field
import feedparser
from pydantic import BaseModel
from DomainModels import Rss
import asyncio

"""force Rss to be a DM & not a module"""

class Rss(BaseModel):
def **next**(self):
yield self

@dataclass(kw_only=True)
class RssFeedReader:

```
krssResult: list[Rss] = field(default_factory=list)

# public commands
async def Read(self, url: str):
    feed = feedparser.parse(url)["entries"]

    kRss = Rss
    for i in range(len(feed)):
        kRss.index = i
        kRss.title = feed[i]["title"]
        # kRss.titleDetail = feed[i]["title_detail"]
        kRss.titleDetail = feed[i]["description"]
        self.AddResult(i, kRss)

    return self.krssResult

def AddResult(self, i, rss: Rss):
    print(i)
    self.krssResult.append(rss)
    print(self.krssResult[i - 1].title)
    print(self.krssResult[i - 1].titleDetail)
```

myTestReader = RssFeedReader()
loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
loop.run_until_complete(myTestReader.Read(url="https://lorem-rss.herokuapp.com/feed"))
loop.close()

result:

0
Lorem ipsum 2024-03-15T14:10:00Z
Eiusmod eiusmod consequat fugiat cillum nisi nisi.
1
Lorem ipsum 2024-03-15T14:09:00Z
Nisi cillum et do sunt enim consequat voluptate id qui sint officia nisi dolore et.
2
Lorem ipsum 2024-03-15T14:08:00Z
Ex et enim est ullamco laborum cupidatat minim pariatur tempor nisi officia.
3
Lorem ipsum 2024-03-15T14:07:00Z
Velit fugiat nostrud anim nostrud.
4
Lorem ipsum 2024-03-15T14:06:00Z
Adipisicing minim cupidatat fugiat non velit elit.
5
Lorem ipsum 2024-03-15T14:05:00Z
Veniam officia labore magna ad.
6
Lorem ipsum 2024-03-15T14:04:00Z
Laborum enim reprehenderit mollit laborum.
7
Lorem ipsum 2024-03-15T14:03:00Z
Mollit amet laboris eu ad fugiat non excepteur nisi dolor do eiusmod aliqua eiusmod.
8
Lorem ipsum 2024-03-15T14:02:00Z
Culpa reprehenderit deserunt mollit enim nostrud ea non minim pariatur nisi.
9
Lorem ipsum 2024-03-15T14:01:00Z
Id et laboris id officia mollit dolor enim.

Can you be more specific and maybe also share how you are calling the method?

Comment: yes the last entry of the rss feed is repeat 50 times

Comment: I am calling this from a flask app, its not that anyway, if I print(self.krssResult) before I return it, it's 50 of the same item, if i follow the other answer here is 50 black RSS() items with no data

Comment: if i add the title to a kRss = [] it works fine, its something to do with the dataclass

Comment: ok I edited and posted the result of my call above. I do not see the repeat in this case. Sorry for not being more helpful!

Comment: ok, I have added the other files from my flask app with DI, I am unsure if that will help but its there, I am sure its something wrong with the Rss dataclass really

Comment: I have never seen this re-definition architecture just to make it an iterator. Surely pydantic will also be yelling about that?